# Method overriding in Typescript with different return types without hack

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

I am trying to use a class adapter pattern in typescript

```
class Source {
    getSomething(): TypeA
}

class Adapter extends Source {
   getSomething(): TypeB {
     const response = super.doSomething();
     // do something with the shape of response
     return response;
   }
}
```

Typescript is complaining that these two types are incompatible. I am not sure if this is something doable in Typescript without typehint `any` or union `TypeA | TypeB`. Imagine a scenario where I want the client code to be able to use both the `Source` and `Adapter` class and still be able to get proper type checks.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe use generics? `class Source<T> { getSomething(): T }`  and  `class Adapter extends Source<TypeB>`?

Comment: It can work I think but it is not scalable. I am using it in apollo server datasources and each class has average 10 methods which I am using adapters for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real reason this is not possible is that since `Adapter` extends `Source`, any instance of `Adapter` should be assignable to a reference of `Source`, and not cause any runtime issues. If `TypeA` and `TypeB` are unrelated, you can have runtime errors from such an assignment:

```
class TypeA { a() { return 0 } }
class Source {
    getSomething(): TypeA {
        return null!
    }
}
class TypeB { b() { return 0 } }
class Adapter extends Source {
   getSomething(): TypeB {
     return null!
   }
}

let source: Source = new Adapter();
source.getSomething().a() // error a is not defined on TypeB which is what  Adapter actually returns
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=102&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHApgQWgb2mAFASk2gCdkAXAVyIDtoAGaAX0YChRIYBlAe0uGU2bQh0AOZluAWzIALAJZUR+AFxwkaAcM3EylGlXIgQAQkHCGzc2yiqUAIUIAjfIRIVqdRiysxUAEzCIpMhE0MgAHkFUvpw8RHwaQmKkkjLyingqCHYJwq660PqGJmYWzMwgZNAQsXwq3Lz8ALwFyADu0H4BQUT4ANzM1Q0AdEkppHIK+EO4BAD0s6FERFwhYNCyMFRcpNC+yABm8si+0Fw0Wcj2rXLA0usw12A7Hf6BwdjAFGCG8NpuVDAgA)

If `TypeB` extends `TypeA` (either class inheritance or structural subtyping) then typescript actually does not complain and allows your definitions:

```
class TypeA { a() { return 0 } }
class Source {
    getSomething(): TypeA {
        return null!
    }
}
class TypeB extends TypeA { b() { return 0 } }
class Adapter extends Source {
   getSomething(): TypeB {
     return null!
   }
}

let source: Source = new Adapter();
source.getSomething().a() // This is ok now
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=44&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHApgQWgb2mAFASk2gCdkAXAVyIDtoAGaAX0YChRIYBlAe0uGU2bQh0AOZluAWzIALAJZUR+AFxwkaAcM3EylGlXIgQAQkHCGzc2yiqUAIWjIAHqWRUAJjAQp0WAEb5CEgpqOkYWKxhUNzBEFyIHZ1cPaG5efgxTUXEuKVI5BWUbZHsMrSDdaH1DEzMLZmYQMmgIHiI+FVS2-gBeSuQAd2gomLj8AG5mFrSAOjFSSRl5RTxp3AIAenW4ORhZGC4Aa0qufqA)

Now to get the compiler to accept your code, you can make `Source` generic (with the generic having a default of `TypeA`), then you would get correct types and only get errors if you try to assign an `Adapter` to a `Source` which is what would cause the runtime error:

```
class TypeA { a() { return 0 } }
class Source<T = TypeA> {
    getSomething(): T {
        return null!
    }
}
class TypeB  { b() { return 0 } }
class Adapter extends Source<TypeB> {
   getSomething(): TypeB {
     return null!
   }
}

let adapter =  new Adapter()
let source: Source = adapter; // this is an error
adapter.getSomething().b() // this is fine and returns TypeB
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHApgQWgb2mAFASk2gCdkAXAVyIDtoAGaAX0YChRIYBlAe0uGQB5Y0ALxwkaAHyZm0WdADmZbgFsyACwCWVefgBccaXKPEylGlXIgQAQhlyGzB2yhiUAIVlYARvkIkK1HSMLM4wqAAmYIikyETQyAAeMVThnDxEfILiblIYdgpKXKqkmtp6rsgeecb+ZtAWVrb2jszMIGTYkdGxIrJUyADu0BFRMUT4bR0Q6Xz63LzIvWBdYwDc0AD0G9AlGjB72DSxRFxEzMujsQB0iqQq6lo6eFc+BFs7mvswAGZai2ApEwBKgwBDuZhAA)

If `Source` is not within your control to change, you could perform some type surgery on it to get it to work by omitting the offending method, but I would not recommend it.

```
class TypeA { a() { return 0 } }
class Source {
    getSomething(): TypeA {
        return null!
    }
}
class TypeB  { b() { return 0 } }
const ModifiedSource = Source as new(...p: ConstructorParameters<typeof Source>) => Omit<Source, 'getSomething'>
class Adapter extends ModifiedSource {
   getSomething(): TypeB {
     return null!
   }
}

let adapter =  new Adapter()
let source: Source = adapter; // this is still an error
adapter.getSomething().b() // this is fine and returns TypeB
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=61&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHApgQWgb2mAFASk2gCdkAXAVyIDtoAGaAX0YChRIYBlAe0uGU2bQh0AOZluAWzIALAJZUR+AFxwkaAcM3EylGlXIgQAQkHCGzc2yiqUAISFYARvkIkK1OoxbAuVCKWgAWS4AE1kAM1lkEO5efgBeaFiiPmwYKmQAdxwAOjyABRUAYV9-InJgUi4ifLAiMClSZCIIAB5SNS5wpJ4U5AA+Anj+6AB5CVlSVuS+ABpoAHIxUkkZeREF-tZwa1QQsEQmomhkAA8mqhCYYLDI6Jn+DFNRcS5GuQVlG2R7J603XTQfSGExmCzMZggMjYfaHZrQRJArLQPYHI74SHQiC9PgqB4ImFo5oAbmgAHoydBSHIYLIYP5ZIZsDRmkRqswwLCjjllqtqet8DlnAQKVSadA6dBIhlmSFtO4-N9bMwgA)

Comment: But does it mean that in Typescript, typical overriding doesn't exists? The one we learn in academics

Comment: @Raheel you can override, just you have to stick to the rules, the overridden method return type must be the same type, or a derived type of the base type. (Some languages , such as C# force the return type of the overridden  method  to be exactly the same as the base type (al least at time of writing, this may change in C#9))